# iOS - How do I know the view that is under the one I'm dragging?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` filled with draggable `(UIView)` `card`s as subviews and I want the `card`s to re-organize themselves (make space for new  when the user drags one of them into the `UIScrollView`.

The problem is: how do I know which of the `UIViews` is under the one I'm dragging, so I can get its index and move it away from the `card` being dragged?

I tried using `hitTest:withEvent:` but I think I'm far from doing it right, since it's returning `nil`.

```
UIView *viewUnderCard = [card hitTest:card.center withEvent:nil];
```

Just started developing for iOS. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, `hitTest:withEvent:` can be used. But @Mysiaq is correct that `pointInside:withEvent:` is probably even better.

You need to make sure that the coordinates are relative to the correct view. If you're using `card.center`, the coordinate system is that of the card's parent view.

The code could look something like this:

```
UIView *container = viewThatHasAllTheCards;
UIView *targetCard = nil;
CGPoint cardInWindow = [draggedCard.superview convertPoint:draggedCard.center toView:nil];
CGPoint cardInContainer = [container convertPoint:cardInWindow fromView:nil];

for (UIView *subview in container.subviews) {
    if (subview == draggedCard) {
        // Skip the dragged card.
        continue;
    }

    if ([subview pointInside:cardInContainer withEvent:nil]) {
        targetCard = subview;
        // If you want the lower-most card, break here.
        // If you want the top-most card, do not break here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I never get inside this: `if ([subview pointInside:p withEvent:nil])`

Comment: You said in another comment that the views are not siblings. I've updated the code to convert the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I was stuck with this for 2 days!

Answer (score 1):

Get point of your touch and then call function

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

for all UIScrollView subviews and function will return you YES if provided CGPoint is inside of its frame.

Comment: +1, `pointInside:withEvent:` is better than `hitTest:withEvent:` here (although both can be used in this case). But the vital part is that the point has to be relative to the correct view.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare bounding rects of two views:

```
CGRect boundsView1 = [view1 convertRect:view1.bounds toView:nil];
CGRect boundsView2 = [view2 convertRect:view2.bounds toView:nil];
Boolean viewsOverlap = CGRectIntersectsRect(boundsView1, boundsView2);
```

From here, you should be able to figure out how to iterate efficiently through your list of views to determine if any overlap.

Comment: If the views are siblings, you can simply do `CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)`.

Comment: Unfortunately the views are not siblings, the dragged card comes from another view. Also, although I know which one is view1, I don't know which one is view2.